# How do I give permission for wsgi to operate in my directory?

Tags: django, apache, permissions, mod-wsgi, wsgi

Apache and wsgi now have permissions problems accessing the directory in which my Django project is stored.  I think I need to get back to having wsgi run as user (or maybe just group) kevin.

I had this working, and I don't know what I did to stop it working, but now I get an permissions error as soon as I get past logging into my app.  Unfortunately, I don't have the apache config under version control.  I'm pretty sure that's where the problem is because restoring a backup of the project from when it was working didn't change anything, but tweaking permissions on the database and the root directory of the project has altered the particulars of the error message.  I wasn't going to give o+w to the whole works, nor did I feel like giving an ACL to every single file or directory.

Background: apache 2 as delivered with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Django 1.11.  Python 3.5.  libsqlite3.0 3.11.0

I thought that what I had in the tail of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf took care of this, in particular the line

```
WSGIProcessGroup kevin
```

because all the files and directories are owned by kevin.kevin, and my evidence seems to indicate that when it was working, it did so because it was running with at least effective group 'kevin' and not the current 'www-data'.

The whole tail of stuff I added to apache2.conf for this project now looks like this:

```
# KOSMANOR: 
# In accordance with https://www.mindchasers.com/dev/apache-install
WSGIDaemonProcess kevin processes=4 threads=12 python-path=/build/comprosloco
WSGIProcessGroup kevin
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /build/comprosloco/comprosloco/wsgi.py

<Directory /build/comprosloco/comprosloco>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

# 29 Jan 2018 on  kosmanor.com
# 6 Mar 2018 revised reference to 1.11, but it's so modified as to be unrecognizable.  Not sure what reference was used.
# 6 Mar 2018 In particular the stuff about virtual environments is ignored here.
# WSGIScriptAlias / is set above in accordance with the mindchaser page
# WSGIPythonPath not set (semms to find my stuff without it)
# WSTIPythonHome is not set (not using a vitual environment yet)

# Added in accordance (somewhat modified) with https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/
#
Alias /static/ /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static/
<Directory /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/django/contrib/admin/static>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 3):

The documentation for `WSGIDaemonProcess` can be found at:

- http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/configuration-directives/WSGIDaemonProcess.html

You possibly can use the `user` and `group` options.

Otherwise the directories and files need to at least be readable by the Apache user on your system. If needing to write files, then the Apache user would need write access to the files and in cases like SQLite also the directory so it can create a database lock file.

Comment: That's a useful link.  But I'm getting lost.  I think I've returned apache2.conf back to where it was, but now I immediately get "you don't have permission to access '/' on this server".  I was doing better than that before.  And 'runserver' works just fine.  So it's clear I need to work on permissions.  But setting user and group did not do it.

Comment: The Apache user still needs to be able to access the directory tree and file for the WSGI script file when mapping URL to the script file. If you want restrictive permissions on the project code directory so is only accessible to you, then put the WSGI script file elsewhere in a directory where Apache can access it. It is only the WSGI script file that Apache user still needs to be able to read the directory for.

Answer (score 1):

Very helpful comments.  I did get it solved, but the details should probably be stated, as something of the sort could happen to others.

1. Unless you do something about it, WSGI is run as the user that Apache normally starts child processes.  On my Ubuntu 16.04, that was 'www-data'.  That user does not normally have permissions on the directories I build with my non-privileged user account.
2. Django is going to need r and x permissions on all directories, and w permission on the database AND THE DIRECTORY WHERE THE DATABASE RESIDES.  The latter is because it creates its transaction and locking files there.
3. If WSGI is failing on account of permissions, the apache error log is your friend.  The normal access log can be helpful too.
4. You can make the WSGI child run as some other user with the WSGIDaemonProcess entry in the apache config file (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf on my system).  I added "user=me group=me' to the entry, where 'me' was my account's and group's names.  That gave it all the permissions it needed.